# How can I reuse this responsive navbar on separate HTML sites

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the other solutions on stackoverflow but they did not work.
The navbar or the banner code is so complex and I can not implement the other solutions.
I want to delete this navbar from all the files (mobile and desktop version) and addd it to a separate HTML file so I can reach from other websites files.
The idea I want to do is, I don't want to change the menu items from every file. Just want to do once.

```
<!-- Header desktop -->
    <div class="container-menu-desktop">

        </div>

        <!-- Header Mobile -->
        <div class="wrap-header-mobile">
            <!-- Logo mobile -->        
            <div class="logo-mobile">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icons/logo-01.png" alt="IMG-LOGO"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Button show menu -->
            <div class="btn-show-menu-mobile hamburger hamburger--squeeze m-r--8">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu Mobile -->
        <div class="menu-mobile">


            <ul class="main-menu-m">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">XXX</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-m">
                        <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                        <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                        <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="arrow-main-menu-m">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu-m">
                        <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                        <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="arrow-main-menu-m">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="info.html">XXX</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--  -->
        <div class="wrap-logo container">
            <!-- Logo desktop -->       
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icons/logo-01.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
            </div>  

            <!-- Banner -->
            <div class="banner-header">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/banner-01.jpg" alt="IMG"></a>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <!-- Navbar STARTS HERE -->
        <!--  -->
        <div class="wrap-main-nav">
            <div class="main-nav">
                <!-- Menu desktop -->
                <nav class="menu-desktop">
                    <a class="logo-stick" href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/icons/logo-01.png" alt="LOGO">
                    </a>
                    <ul class="main-menu">
                        <li class="main-menu-item">
                            <a href="index.html">XXX</a>    

                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-item">
                            <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-item">
                            <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>  
                        </li>

                        <li class="main-menu-item">
                            <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>  
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                                <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                                <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                            </ul>   
                        </li>   
                        <li class="main-menu-item">
                            <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>  
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                                <li><a href="XXX.html">XXX</a></li>
                            </ul>   
                        </li>   
                        <li class="mega-menu-item">
                            <a href="XXX.html">XXX</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="mega-menu-item">
                            <a href="info.html">XXX</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: You can load only a single html file to a browser (iframes are probably not a good solution here). Hence you've to combine the files at the server before sending the page to the client. For this we need information about your server, the used language and possible frameworks specifically. You can of course load the menu with AJAX, but still the server info is needed.

Comment: I am a beginner could you please explain what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using an .
Just host the navbar as a unique site and than reference it like this:

```
 <iframe src="http://host:port/navbar"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do I have to save the navbar like "navbar.html" ?
What is host:port?

Answer (score 0):

1. Place this file on a server
2. Fetch file contents through ajax
3. Replace this content with Javacript/Jquery.